# How to remove observation's correlation loading points in correlation loading plot in SAS?

Tags: sas, multivariate-testing

[Correlation Loading Plot from Pro PLS in SAS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP2vJ.png)

Hi All,

I used Proc PLS to do a multivariate analysis and got a plot as attached. How can I remove the green colored points in the picture? I think they are the observations' correlation values. For example, I have 90 observations, and each of them will have a loading value on factor1 and factor2, so there will be 90 green points shown in the picture. Who can tell me which option can suppress them?
for example, data is like this:

par1    par2    par3    par4    par5    par6    par7    location
2680    0.546089996 237 1   0.172   2.25    305 5
3750    0.54836587  140 1.55    0.111   1.06    425 5
3590    0.54878718  168 1.27    0.131   0.969   516 5
2390    0.549510935 183 1.07    0.096   1.84    260 5
3780    0.549631747 140 1.12    0.118   1.98    472 5
2790    0.549934008 200 1.1 0.221   2.13    321 5
2880    0.5499945   227 1.14    0.185   1.54    439 5
2910    0.550357733 259 1.31    0.116   1.31    289 5
2420    0.550842789 177 1.32    0.044067423 1.95    260 5
3850    0.550964187 128 1.41    0.117   1.08    471 5
3530    0.552425146 165 1.23    0.11    1.57    494 5
2730    0.552913856 223 1.03    0.17    2   330 5
3130    0.553158535 252 1.02    0.174   2.13    322 5
3040    0.553709856 272 1.21    0.155   1.97    317 5
3830    0.554139421 153 1.27    0.137   1.47    455 5
3930    0.554569654 164 1.17    0.116   1.5 481 5
2430    0.554569654 136 1.3 0.198   2.11    226 8
3630    0.555247085 137 1.17    0.1 1.75    413 5
2490    0.555432126 176 1.06    0.113   1.39    236 5
3490    0.555555556 166 1.28    0.044444444 1.65    465 5
3840    0.556173526 164 1.23    0.0949  1.66    470 5
2480    0.556173526 239 1.28    0.102   2.2 238 5
3760    0.556173526 191 1.33    0.131   2.12    447 5
3850    0.556173526 174 1.35    0.241   2.42    381 3
3410    0.557413601 174 1.14    0.107   1.48    419 5
2960    0.559284116 229 1.08    0.165   1.99    304 5
3410    0.559284116 137 1.19    0.291   2.17    375 8
3300    0.560538117 121 1.13    0.153   1.82    352 8
3090    0.560538117 134 1.16    0.167   1.17    416 4
3210    0.560538117 124 1.09    0.172   0.82    390 4
3950    0.560538117 130 1.29    0.199   1.89    440 4
3300    0.561167228 131 1.06    0.242   2.45    367 8
2210    0.561167228 162 0.885   0.288   3.32    208 4
3170    0.561797753 126 1.3 0.151   1.31    388 4
2740    0.561797753 96.1    1.22    0.245   0.827   254 3
3750    0.561797753 144 1.08    0.257   2.62    366 3
3640    0.562429696 120 1.32    0.159   1.63    347 8
3210    0.563063063 148 1.29    0.206   2.18    352 8
2300    0.563697858 179 0.936   0.181   2.29    223 2
3410    0.564334086 141 0.856   0.136   2.03    370 8
3500    0.564334086 126 1.38    0.177   1.45    355 8
3470    0.564334086 101 0.989   0.222   1.84    349 3
2260    0.564334086 171 0.942   0.224   2.08    219 2
2220    0.564334086 180 0.956   0.281   1.84    219 4
2340    0.564971751 165 1.05    0.228   2.25    240 8
2380    0.564971751 161 0.976   0.287   1.6 214 4
3220    0.56561086  148 1.21    0.121   0.568   520 6
3920    0.566251416 176 1.08    0.045300113 2.26    637 6
3830    0.566251416 137 1.48    0.203   1.23    387 3
2510    0.566251416 152 1.24    0.222   1.84    223 8
2760    0.566251416 168 0.994   0.282   1.31    280 4
2640    0.566251416 154 0.979   0.345   1.52    291 4
3570    0.566893424 165 1.33    0.155   2.18    505 6
3170    0.566893424 126 1.08    0.162   1.41    341 4
3700    0.566893424 159 1.3 0.17    1.64    449 4
3250    0.566893424 104 1.32    0.2 1.37    372 8
3740    0.566893424 159 1.23    0.216   1.69    409 1
3380    0.566893424 163 1.53    0.245   2.19    367 3
3240    0.56753689  136 1.07    0.153   1.88    383 4
3400    0.56753689  109 1.36    0.161   1.16    420 4
3760    0.56753689  150 0.93    0.169   1.68    537 4
3560    0.56753689  123 1.03    0.193   2.32    374 8
2360    0.56753689  163 0.697   0.235   1.94    243 8
2430    0.56753689  166 0.762   0.247   2.31    231 8
3330    0.568181818 148 1.11    0.174   2   393 4
3080    0.568181818 139 1.13    0.188   2.08    349 8
3230    0.568181818 116 1.23    0.199   1.77    328 8
2180    0.568181818 144 1.01    0.215   2.13    207 8
2520    0.568181818 128 0.809   0.369   1.65    306 4
3320    0.568828214 152 1.15    0.14    1.65    395 4
2300    0.568828214 134 0.908   0.221   1.56    233 8
3730    0.568828214 141 1.58    0.238   1.96    405 3
3800    0.568828214 160 1.24    0.241   2.2 402 3
2440    0.568828214 153 1.03    0.258   1.89    223 4
3910    0.568828214 209 1.26    0.275   2.26    350 3
4010    0.569476082 139 1.28    0.045558087 1.7 602 6
2340    0.570125428 167 1.1 0.18    1.57    208 2
2360    0.570125428 176 0.704   0.2 1.6 219 2
3490    0.570776256 171 1.43    0.269   2.4 360 3
2620    0.571428571 132 1.09    0.202   1.8 224 8
3740    0.571428571 172 1.27    0.256   1.92    355 3
3600    0.57208238  128 1.16    0.17    1.94    434 4
3360    0.57208238  150 1.18    0.171   1.81    353 1
3620    0.57208238  131 1.28    0.177   2.24    360 3
3560    0.57208238  139 1.15    0.229   1.9 366 3
2740    0.572737686 277 0.876   0.171   1.71    290 10
2340    0.572737686 148 0.964   0.231   1.18    250 6
2760    0.572737686 168 0.905   0.303   2.1 264 4
2890    0.572737686 204 0.857   0.331   2.32    272 2
code is :

```
proc pls data=check method=rrr;
class location;
model par1-par7=location;
run;
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your code using a SASHELP dataset or similar?

Comment: @Joe Thank you, has added.

Comment: Do you want to suppress the `correlations loading plot` itself, or just the green overprint (wanting still the circle, locations, and factors)?

Comment: @Joe I just want to suppress the green overprint, still want to keep the circle, locations and factors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I don't think there's a *simple* way to do what you're looking for.  You may want to construct your own graph.

You can get the template for the graph; I'll paste that here. Unfortunately all of the data printed on the graph is printed in a single statement, so it's not helpful to just comment out one line: you comment out the `scatterplot x=CORRX y=CORRY` and you remove *all* of the data.  I also don't see that ODS Graphics Editor will be able to do this.

You would be best off probably constructing your own chart using this as a base, but calling it from `PROC SGRENDER` so you can control how the data comes in.

Here's the template, and you'll see the spot I'm talking about:

```
proc template;                                                                
   define statgraph Stat.PLS.Graphics.CorrLoadPlot;                           
      dynamic Radius1 Radius2 Radius3 Radius4 xLabel xShortLabel yLabel       
         yShortLabel CorrX CorrXLab TraceX CorrY CorrYLab TraceY _byline_     
         _bytitle_ _byfootnote_;                                              
      BeginGraph /;                                                           
         entrytitle "Correlation Loading Plot";                               
         layout overlayequated / equatetype=square commonaxisopts=(           
            tickvaluelist=(-1.0 -0.75 -0.5 -0.25 0 0.25 0.5 0.75 1.0) viewmin=
            -1 viewmax=1) xaxisopts=(label=XLABEL shortlabel=XSHORTLABEL      
            offsetmin=0.05 offsetmax=0.05 gridDisplay=auto_off) yaxisopts=(   
            label=YLABEL shortlabel=YSHORTLABEL offsetmin=0.05 offsetmax=0.05 
            gridDisplay=auto_off);                                            
            ellipseparm semimajor=RADIUS1 semiminor=RADIUS1 slope=0.0 xorigin=
               0.0 yorigin=0.0 / clip=true display=(outline) outlineattrs=(   
               pattern=dash) datatransparency=0.75;                           
            scatterplot x=XCIRCLE1LABEL y=YCIRCLE1LABEL / markercharacter=    
               CIRCLE1LABEL datatransparency=0.75 primary=true;               
            ellipseparm semimajor=RADIUS2 semiminor=RADIUS2 slope=0.0 xorigin=
               0.0 yorigin=0.0 / clip=true display=(outline) outlineattrs=(   
               pattern=dash) datatransparency=0.75;                           
            scatterplot x=XCIRCLE2LABEL y=YCIRCLE2LABEL / markercharacter=    
               CIRCLE2LABEL datatransparency=0.75 primary=true;               
            ellipseparm semimajor=RADIUS3 semiminor=RADIUS3 slope=0.0 xorigin=
               0.0 yorigin=0.0 / clip=true display=(outline) outlineattrs=(   
               pattern=dash) datatransparency=0.75;                           
            scatterplot x=XCIRCLE3LABEL y=YCIRCLE3LABEL / markercharacter=    
               CIRCLE3LABEL datatransparency=0.75 primary=true;               
            ellipseparm semimajor=RADIUS4 semiminor=RADIUS4 slope=0.0 xorigin=
               0.0 yorigin=0.0 / clip=true display=(outline) outlineattrs=(   
               pattern=dash) datatransparency=0.75;                           
            scatterplot x=XCIRCLE4LABEL y=YCIRCLE4LABEL / markercharacter=    
               CIRCLE4LABEL datatransparency=0.75 primary=true;               
            scatterplot x=CORRX y=CORRY / group=CORRGROUP Name="ScatterVars"  
               markercharacter=CORRLABEL rolename=(_id1=_ID1 _id2=_ID2 _id3=  
               _ID3 _id4=_ID4 _id5=_ID5) tip=(y x group markercharacter _id1  
               _id2 _id3 _id4 _id5) tiplabel=(y=CORRXLAB x=CORRYLAB group=    
               "Corr Type" markercharacter="Corr ID");                        
            SeriesPlot x=TRACEX y=TRACEY / tip=(y x) tiplabel=(y=CORRYLAB x=  
               CORRXLAB);                                                     
         endlayout;                                                           
         if (_BYTITLE_)                                                       
            entrytitle _BYLINE_ / textattrs=GRAPHVALUETEXT;                   
         else                                                                 
            if (_BYFOOTNOTE_)                                                 
               entryfootnote halign=left _BYLINE_;                            
            endif;                                                            
         endif;                                                               
      EndGraph;                                                               
   end;                                                                       
run;
```

I would consider posting this on communities.sas.com and seeing if one of the developers can give you more specific information; Sanjay and Dan often post there and may well be able to give you a simpler answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will have a try!